# Displaying all results of execution

Tags: python, terminal, execution

When I execute a python program, the results starts to appear quickly and I can't read it all. It just flushes over my screen.
When the execution ends, I can no longer see the first displays, because the terminal display space is limited.

How save the output, so I can read all of it?

Comment: You can output your result in a file, for example `$ myscript.python > output.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here.

- Add a breakpoint and learn how to use the debugger. Once you add this command (`import pdb;pdb.set_trace() # this will take some learning so look up what pdb is online. actually, i prefer 'ipdb' instead.`), the code will stop at that specific point when you execute it.
- Save it to a file (`python file.py > filename.txt`) and then read it afterwards. Bonus: Before you ask yourself, where are my outputs? https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file
- (More advanced) Your code is spitting out too much garbage output. You can remove some of the code or use python logging filters.

Answer (score 0):

May be platform dependant.
On Linux you can also pipe your program output into your favorite pager (less for example) if you don't want to write it to a file.

```sh
    python file.py | less
```